# how to Build a referral and earning system in django python

Tags: django

i am currently working on a system, when  a user register and do a particular task  they will be credited with a certain amount, also the app will have a referral system every user will have a unique referral id when you invite somebody with your code when there do a task you will also earn a certain amount as a referral commission
i have already design my data base  but i don't know where to start from here, if any one here has build a similar app should please share they code with me,
if I didn't deliver this job my work will be at risk
thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you want to create a model to hold referral code, something like:

```
class Referral(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    referral_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

now every user has a referal code. then some on signup using this referal code both gets rewarded(eg: credits increased by 20$ for both users).